# How to match the current path to URL patterns?

Tags: python, django

I am doing a Django tutorial in writing my Django App, part 3. So far, running the server brings up an error:
[a screenshot of what the error displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7fZD.png)

These are the python scripts I've entered so far;

polls/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse 
from .models import Question
from django.template import loader
from .models import Question


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index. Too bright")

def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)

# Latest Questions List

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    output = ', '.join([q.question_text for q in latest_question_list])
    return HttpResponse(output)

# Leave the rest of the views (detail, results, vote) unchanged

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Question
# ...
def detail(request, question_id):
    try:
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Question does not exist")
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import Question
# ...
def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/templates/polls/index', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/templates/polls/index', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

polls/index.html.py

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
        path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

polls/detail.html.py

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
<li>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

polls/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Question

admin.site.register(Question)
```

mysite/settings.py

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parents[1]


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '49n_-36s382!oc1#a$98rr$@z)=y%+0h*medw^ept0rk+bkc&v'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True  

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['/polls/templates/polls'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite2.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-password- 
validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 
    'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Those are the python scripts and I hope someone can assist me as I am still a python programming beginner. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After starting your project server, Django will go to your project/urls.py first then if there are additional apps URLs, it will go to each app's URLs(app/urls.py) respectively.

In your mysite/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('polls', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

In polls/urls.py

```
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
```

Based on the above settings, the following urls

```
polls/ 
polls/question_id/ 
polls/question_id/results/
polls/question_id/vote/
```

Comment: I did this before and it still could not match the current path @JunZhou

Comment: I noticed there are many index functions in your polls.views.py, could you try to remove or comment out all other index functions and just leave the first "Hello, world" one?

Comment: I've edit my question and added the mysite/settings.py script. Can you please just check if there are some potential errors in it @JunZhou

Comment: Should ROOT_URLCONF be 'mysite.urls'？

Comment: Sorry, my mysite name for this project is mysite2.urls